# TypeError: (0 , _expressJwt2.default) is not a function

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, babeljs

While setting up mongodb with node js for local hosting i am facing this error in this part of the code:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';

const TOKENTIME = 60*60*24*90;
const SECRET = "W3 CHAT 4 FUN";

let authenticate = expressJwt({ secret: SECRET });
```

the error message is:

```
var authenticate = (0, _expressJwt2.default)({ secret: SECRET });
                                            ^

TypeError: (0 , _expressJwt2.default) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/shoai/OneDrive/Desktop/mac-chat-api/src/middleware/authMiddleware.js:7:20)
```

am stuck in this for like 2 days

i was triying setup mongodb for local hosting api's

Comment: Read [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) in the documentation `import { expressJwt } from 'express-jwt';`

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: same error messge